# Create select nested subquery to count different items from one column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a following table would like to get count in one table as displayed below.
Grouped by system and two columns counting the Locked/Unlocked status.

```
 |SYSTEM|LOCK_STAT|
 ------------------
 |A     |Locked   |
 |A     |Unlocked |
 |A     |Locked   |
 |B     |Locked   |
 |B     |Unlocked |
 |B     |Unlocked |
```

And the result should be as follows:

```
 |SYSTEM|UNLOCKED|LOCKED|
 | A    |       1|     2|
 | B    |       2|     1|
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select system,
       sum(case when lock_stat = 'Locked' then 1 else 0 end) as locked,
       sum(case when lock_stat = 'Unocked' then 1 else 0 end) as unlocked
from t
group by system;
```

Comment: Thank you! Any chance to help with how this translates to MS Access, please?

Comment: @Kokokoko . . . This question is tagged SQL Server.  If you have a question about MS Access, then that would be a new question.

Comment: Sure, will do. Thank you.